# Unable to RDP through VPN

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, remote-desktop

After connecting to a work VPN I am unable to access the network drives or folders either in windows explorer or RDP servers on the work network.

**What I have tried:**

I have two machines in my house on the same network (Both wired). One connects to the VPN and can access the shared drives and can RDP to the works servers.

The second machine can connect to the VPN but cannot access the shared storage or RDP.

The second machine can RDP others servers outside of the network.

I have no antivirus and have disabled windows firewall.

I have enabled network discovery and public sharing to match the setup of the first machine.

**What I have eliminated:**

- Router (As first machine works)
- Firewall (As it's disabled)
- RDP (As it can access external servers)

I have concluded that the blocking must be configuration on the second machine but am unsure what settings to check. Can anyone offer suggestions what I can look at?

Comment: Is the non-working machine on Public or Private network connection?  Do you have Network Discovery and File/Print Sharing turned ON?  Is Client for Microsoft Networks enabled in the non-working machine?

Comment: Have you contacted your Network Administrator for assistance?

Comment: What VPN software are you using? Are you trying to have both PCs connected simultaneously? Do they show identical routes through the VPN (`route print`) once connected? Do they both use the same DNS servers (`ipconfig /all`)? Are you connecting to the storage/RDP servers by short name, or by full DNS name, or by IPv4 address, or by IPv6 address?